# Java-Program terminating early without error-message after being called from C++ via JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

So I'm having some java-Code that I want to call from C++ via JNI. It's done by the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    JavaVM * jvm;
    JNIEnv* env = create_vm(&jvm);
    invoke_class( env );
}

JNIEnv* create_vm(JavaVM ** jvm) {
    JNIEnv* env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption options;
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=<path_to_java_class>:<path_to_jars>";
    vm_args.options = &options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

    int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void **)&env, &vm_args);
    if(ret < 0)
        printf("\nUnable to Launch JVM\n");
    return env;
}

void invoke_class(JNIEnv* env) {
    jclass helloWorldClass;
    helloWorldClass = env->FindClass("A");

    if (env->ExceptionCheck()){
        std::cout << "EXCEPTION OCCURED: " << std::endl;
        env->ExceptionDescribe();
    }
}

call_main(env, helloWorldClass);

void call_main(JNIEnv* env, jclass hClass){
    jmethodID mainMethod;
    jobjectArray applicationArgs;
    jstring applicationArg0;
    jstring applicationArg1;
    mainMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(hClass, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");

    applicationArgs = env->NewObjectArray(2, env->FindClass("java/lang/String"), NULL);
    applicationArg0 = env->NewStringUTF("planes.txt");
    applicationArg1 = env->NewStringUTF("out.txt");
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(applicationArgs, 0, applicationArg0);
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(applicationArgs, 1, applicationArg1);

    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(hClass, mainMethod, applicationArgs);
}
```

The corresponding Java-Code that is called is as follows:

```
public class A{
    import org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory;
    import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;

    private OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(PelletReasonerFactory.THE_SPEC);

    public A() {        
        System.out.println("hi2");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("hi1");

        A app = new A();

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Processing took " + (stop - start) + " ms");
        System.out.println("Normal program end.");
    }
}
```

Okay, so if I'm now executing the C++-Code I get the following output:

```
hi1
```

without any error-messages, the program terminates correctly. However, I would expect the output to be something like:

```
hi1
hi2
Processing took 0ms
Normal program end.
```

It seems like calling the constructor just doesn't happen and the code after that isn't executed at all.

However, if I remove the line

```
private OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(PelletReasonerFactory.THE_SPEC);
```

the output is correct.

Since leaving out this isn't an option, what is happening here? How is it even possible that the program is terminating without an error-message although it shouldn't be finished at all?

I've tried to put in something like `Thread.sleep(10000)` to see if it has something to do with the time that given call takes, but that doesn't seem to be a problem at all.

EDIT: sry, I forgot to change the class-name.
EDIT2: I should mention that the java-code ist running perfectly fine when it is not called out of a C++-environment

Comment: The java code doesn't even compile...

Comment: sorry, i forgot to change the class-name

Comment: There are also imports inside the class, which aren't allowed. Can you please post a full working example?

Comment: Does control return to the C++ code? I.e. if you put some `cout << "Hi" << std::endl` at the end of `main`, does it show when you run the program?

Comment: yep, the output does show - i think it has something to do with the jar-files.. if i put the `options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=<path_to_java_class>:<path_to_jars>"` in a .sh-file and run it, the program does exactly what i want it to do.. is there a way to get the jvm-error-messages displayed if you call java-code from c++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It had something to do with the jar-files and some file-locations. Sorry for bothering for nothing!